# HttpURLConnection.connect can connect to "https" but not "http"

Tags: android, webserver, httpurlconnection

I am trying to connect a http webpage using the following codes in Android system. The http webpage can not be connected, but https such as https://wwww.google.com can be successfully connected. Using `getHeaderFields()`, can get correct header for https://wwww.google.com, but get {} for http websites.

```
String link = "http://www.android.com/";
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
conn.connect();
```

Comment: Unencrypted ("cleartext") HTTP operations are banned by default on Android 9 and higher.